# "best c++ preprocessor macro" question closure

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I created a question on Stack Overflow about the best C++ pre-processor Macros to go with the other pre-existing question about the worst ones. I made the mistake of including some nifty examples in the question which--even if they weren't controversial--wasn't a good idea anyway. They should have been in an answer and probably a little time after the question was asked. The question was closed before anyone could give an answer. Most comments on the question were on the macro examples I had given but there were a few supportive ones of the idea of the thread (if not of the usefulness of my examples).

I can't find the thread anymore. Was it deleted? If so may I retry?

Comment: Even though my answer says you can't do this, +1 for coming here to ask instead of just spamming the main site inconsiderately.

Comment: Do you have another account? I can't find it on the one that's linked to this Meta account.

Comment: Only one account, a Google account, alan2here@gmail.com associated with various stack sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The "pre-existing questions" exist for historical reasons; new subjective questions are no longer allowed.

Comment: Thanks, a good answer. If it does still exist in a closed form then I would prefer it to be deleted entirly. I will not retry.

Answer (score 3):

There's little point, it is very likely that it will just get closed again.  This time probably with a flurry of downvotes from ticked-off users.  Review [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the kind of questions you should **not** ask.  Yours seems to match the first three bullets:

- every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it was deleted, since I'm not a 10k user, but I humbly submit that you may not retry. "List of X" questions like "what's the worst C++ preprocessor" were wildly popular when SO started. Then they landed in sort of a gray area during 2010 with half the community loving them and half hating them. Today the policy is pretty solidly "questions like this are off-topic, but we're not going to actively hunt down and delete old ones."